# How to make python 3.7 default in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: python-3.x, linux

I would like to install tensorrt binding for python3 on Ubuntu 20.04 ( https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/archives/tensorrt-700/tensorrt-install-guide/index.html#installing-debian ) . This Ubuntu has python 3.8 as a default, but those tensorrt bindings needs python 3.7 or lower.

The package is installed via `sudo apt-get install python3-libnvinfer-dev`  . But this crash because of python 3.8 . So I have installed also python 3.7 via `sudo apt-get install python3.7` so I can access 3.7 running command python3.7 . I have also made a ln -s /usr/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python3 to make a python3 command opennning the 3.7 version. But aptget still has a problem and python3.7 is not visible for it. What can I do to make python 3.7 native in Ubuntu 20.04 or how to tell apt-get to look in /usr/bin/python3.7 location? Thanks

Comment: Can you post which command is giving you an error and the actual error message?

Comment: Yes. using sudo apt-get install python3-libnvinfer-dev , I am getting an error `Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-libnvinfer : Depends: python3 (< 3.7) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`
`

Comment: which python3 gets me /home/tom/miniconda3/bin/python3.7

Answer (score 0):

Check if http://web.mit.edu/6.00/www/handouts/pybuntu.html helps.
unbuntu seems to ahvve update-alternative
Didn't try it myself.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem. But i don't know how to make python3.7 the default in Ubuntu 20.04.

[Download](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-tensorrt-download) the tar file install package of your desired TensorRT version. Extract it. Navigate to the extracted folder and then to the python folder. You will find the `.whl` files for the TensorRT python API. Try installing with pip.

In your case it should be like this(if you are trying to install TensorRT 7.1):

```
python3.7 -m pip install tensorrt-7.1.3.4-cp37-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

I found this procedure from the official TensorRT [github repository](https://github.com/NVIDIA/TensorRT#optional---recommended-installing-the-tensorrt-python-api-bindings)

Comment: this is not enough, somehow .so files should get to the system path to make trt invocable from python